# Get list of queue names in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have tried below code to get list of queues in ActiveMQ. But its not working. I have 4 queues in my ActiveMQ.

```
try {
ActiveMQConnection.makeConnection(URL).start();
Set<ActiveMQQueue> allque= ActiveMQConnection.makeConnection().getDestinationSource().getQueues();

Iterator<ActiveMQQueue> itr= allque.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
ActiveMQQueue q= itr.next();
System.out.println(q.getQueueName());
}
} catch (Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please let me know any correction in my code or some new code get it done.

Comment: Which error and/or putput do you get with that code?

Comment: I am getting no error or exception and no output I am getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Destination Source functionality is not a guaranteed way to find the destinations on the Broker.  The functionality can fail to provide any results in a number of cases such as when the advisory feature on the Broker is disabled or the client has been configured not to watch for advisories.  You also query for destination immediately which doesn't necessarily allow for the time needed for the advisories to be dispatched to the client from the Broker.

A more reliable mechanism is the [JMX support](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) on the Broker which provides methods for obtaining lists of destinations along with a host of other information about the running broker instance.

There are plenty of [articles](http://java.dzone.com/articles/managing-activemq-jmx-apis) out there showing how to use JMX with ActiveMQ.

Comment: It would be great if you can explain this using some code example.

Comment: Try a google search, there's tons of articles out there on this topic already.  Also you can look at the ActiveMQ unit tests for examples of using the JMX API.

Answer (score 0):

you have to invoke **getDestinationSource().getQueues()** on the same connection

```
try {
    ActiveMQConnection conn = ActiveMQConnection.makeConnection(URL);
    conn.start();

    Set<ActiveMQQueue> allque= conn.getDestinationSource().getQueues();
    Iterator<ActiveMQQueue> itr= allque.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
      ActiveMQQueue q= itr.next();
      System.out.println(q.getQueueName());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
    ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) activeMQConnectionFactory.createConnection();

    connection.start();

    DestinationSource ds = connection.getDestinationSource();
    Set<ActiveMQQueue> queues = ds.getQueues();

    for (ActiveMQQueue activeMQQueue : queues) {
        try {
            System.Out.Println(activeMQQueue.getQueueName());
            
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    connection.close();re
```