# Listing available queues in ActiveMQ Apache.NMS in C#.net

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, activemq-classic

Is there a way to list out all the active queues in ActiveMQ. I am using Apache.NMS for communicating with ActiveMQ from C#.

I am not seeing any direct methods in the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this.

```
public void Test(ISession Session)
{    
    String QUEUE_ADVISORY_DESTINATION = "ActiveMQ.Advisory.Queue";
    IDestination dest = Session.GetTopic(QUEUE_ADVISORY_DESTINATION);

    using (IMessageConsumer consumer = Session.CreateConsumer(dest))
    {
        IMessage advisory;

        while ((advisory = consumer.Receive()) != null)
        {
            ActiveMQMessage amqMsg = advisory as ActiveMQMessage;

            if (amqMsg.DataStructure != null)
            {
                DestinationInfo info = amqMsg.DataStructure as DestinationInfo;
                if (info != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("   Queue: " + info.Destination.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Listing Complete.");    
}
```

This is not a guaranteed way of listing queues. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24388325/4123805).

Comment: Trying this.. Thanks ... At least got a direction.

Comment: I did not get a list of queues. This method subscribes to messages when a queue is started or stopped. Perhaps the message for the creation of a queue may disappear after some time?

Answer (score 4):

Solution above contains one defect. If you will try to get message like this:

```
consumer.Receive()
```

you will wait infinitely long time while new event won't be occurred with queues information into ActiveMQ.

I recommend to set timeout:

```
consumer.Receive(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000))
```

and see example [offitial site](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/activemq-enumerate-destination-using-advisory-messages.html)

Comment: The official site has a more comprehensive solution, thanks !